# SQL Server trigger count updated columns before update

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have a table called "Users" with  (id, name, lastname, dni, dob, city and lastUpdated)

What I want to do is, execute a trigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE and inside it count the number of columns that will be updated, and if the only column to be updated is "lasUpdated" column, then do not update anything.

```
CREATE TRIGGER USER_TRIGGER
ON USERS
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
/* if the updated column is ONLY lasUpdated */
IF (COUNT(UPDATED_CLOUMNS) == 1 && UPDATED_COLUMN == "lasUpdated")
BEGIN 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RETURN 
END
GO
```

Any idea of how can achieve it? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `columns_updated()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you'll need to actually run the update and print the bit pattern to know which pattern you are looking for,

Comment: You probably don't want an `instead of update` trigger either as you then have to manually carry out any desired updates. You can accomplish your stated goal with and `after update` trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is do the update in your INSTEAD OF trigger with:

```
WHERE inserted.Col1<>deleted.Col1
OR inserted.Col2<>deleted.Col2
etc, for all columns except "lasUpdated"
```

Note that if any of the columns can be NULL, you'll need to handle that in the logic as well.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion, it helped me a lot.